# How to shut down my laptop which is stuck on a black screen after accidentally removing pendrive of Kubuntu Live

Tags: kubuntu

I wanted to install Kubuntu, but before that I wanted to try it, so I used a pendrive with a Live Kubuntu image. However, when It was loading, I accidentally removed the pendrive. Now my laptop is stuck on black screen, but I can still move the mouse on that black screen.

I tried to shut it down by pressing the power button and also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>, but it didn't work.

How to shut down my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to press and hold the power button until the system shut down.